# Firefox is not getting launched with webdriver js and jasmine

Tags: jasmine, jasmine-reporters

I am using selenium WebDriverJS with Jasmine framework.I am trying to execute simple test to launch firefox browser in Win8. But browser is not getting launched and test gets executed.
Kindly assist.